# Difference in callus formation during healing of bones of different origin

Tags: pathology, bone-biology

My study material from pathology states that during fracture healing after hemorrhage and coagulum formation the mesenchymal progenital cells from periostium that are closer to the fracture differentiate into chondrocytes and form hyaline cartilage, while the ones that are farther differentiate into osteoblast.

Result is production of hyaline cartilage in which enchondrial ossification and subsequent remodeling into lamelar bone occurs.

My **question** is: Does this enchondrial ossification also occur in bones in which **Intramembranous ossification** normally occur during development? (e.g. clavicle and some skull bones.)

NOTE: 
in [this stackexchange post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20626/what-happens-to-bones-that-do-not-heal/20627#20627) and [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bone_healing) on this topic, only chondrocytes are noted.